# How to drop null values with a native Oracle XML DB Web Service?

Tags: xml, web-services, oracle, oracle11g

I am using native Oracle XML DB Web Services (using a PL/SQL function with a web service). 
I want to drop null values (put nothing in the output (no XML element)). 
It's working with Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 but not with Oracle 11.2.0.3.0.

Just to clarify... I don't want to consume a webservice with PL/SQL, I want to publish my PL/SQL packages/procedures/functions as a web service!

Hope someone can help me. 
Thank you.

In this example is the column "country" null.

Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 (this is what I want):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
  <GET_PERSONOutput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TESTSTUFF/GET_PERSON">
        <RETURN>
          <PERSON>
          <PERSON_ID>3</PERSON_ID>
          <FIRST_NAME>Harry</FIRST_NAME>
          <LAST_NAME>Potter</LAST_NAME>
        </PERSON>
      </RETURN>
    </GET_PERSONOutput>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Oracle 11.2.0.3.0:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GET_PERSONOutput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TESTSTUFF/GET_PERSON">
     <RETURN>
        <PERSON>
           <PERSON_ID>3</PERSON_ID>
           <FIRST_NAME>Harry</FIRST_NAME>
           <LAST_NAME>Potter</LAST_NAME>
           <COUNTRY/>
        </PERSON>
     </RETURN>
    </GET_PERSONOutput>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all people with the same problem:

I created a Oracle Service request for this problem and the Oracle support says:

> This does not exist for access via procedures/functions. Here the WSDL is
>   driven from function definition which has no way to specify null behavior.

Hope this information is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using XMLFOREST instead of XMLELEMENT will hide the tags of any empty data.

The example query to generate the SOAP request you want would look something like this:

```
SELECT XMLFOREST(XMLFOREST(p.id as "PERSON_ID",
                           p.first_name as "FIRST_NAME",
                           p.last_name as "LAST_NAME",
                           p.country as "COUNTRY"
                           ) as "PERSON")
   FROM PERSON_TABLE p WHERE p.id=3
```

I'm not sure why, but XMLELEMENT leaves empty tags in the XML.  Hopefully this works for you!

Added: a useful article on XMLFOREST vs. XMLELEMENT - http://www.mandsconsulting.com/xmlforest-vs-xmlelement-missing-vs-empty-in-sqlx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if you using "Native Oracle XML DB Web Services", the database will do this things for you. You write a package, procedure or a function without using XMLELEMENT or XMLFOREST directly. Here is a useful article: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/native-oracle-xml-db-web-services-11gr1.php